# "The time and place" or "the time and the place"

Tags: grammaticality, definite-articles, parallelism

> *A. He still hasn't told us the time and place of the meeting.*
>   *B. He still hasn't told us the time and **the** place of the meeting.*

Q1: Which of the above sentences is correct and why? More specifically, do we say "the time and place of..." or "the time and the place of..."?

Q2: Do they sound unnatural or uncommon in any way other than what I already asked in question 1? For example, is it more common to say "the meeting time and place" or "the time and place of the meeting"?

Answer (score 2):

The first is the everyday expression: 'This is not the time and place to raise the matter'.

A second definite article might be used either for emphasis, or where both the time and the place have individual significance.

E.g. Parent to child: 'Two o'clock in the morning, when staying in someone else's house, is neither the time, nor the place to do your brass-band trumpet practice.'

Answer (score 1):

I think the first one is used when "time"and "place" is not meant to be separated. Example: "This is not the time and place for that". Ít's more on statement purposes. Whereas the second is more of the literal meaning (separation of time and place is intended) and question purposes.